# null check is done but throws 'Null check operator used on a null value'

Tags: flutter

I use `sentry` to check error from production app.

I get `Null check operator used on a null value` error message.

[image]

> reg_sign_up_screen.dart in _RegSignUpScreenState.initState. at line 376 within onldocc_flutter

The code of line 376 in req_sign_up_screen is below.

[image]

```
 FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
      if (user != null) {
        setState(() {
          _createdUserId = user.uid;
        });
      } else {}
    });
```

As you can see, I already do null check with  `if (user != null) {...}`.

But I don't know why this null check error comes.

Do you have any idea on this? Please help me!

Comment: can you check if FirebaseAuth instance has been initialized

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh I do `await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
      );` in main.dart And as you can see above, I access instance `Firebase.instance..` is there any more thing to initialize FirebaseAuth?

Comment: I wonder what it would be hiding on else, maybe try-actch and breakpoint will provide better hint

Comment: I change the code as below.

 `FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
      try {
        if (user != null) {
          setState(() {
            _createdUserId = user.uid;
          });
        }
      } catch (e) {
        // ignore: avoid_print
        print("authStateChanges -> $e");
      }
    });`

Comment: try like `try{ FirebaseAuth.......}catch..`

Comment: The error "Null check operator used on null value" happens when you use the "!" operator on a null value, like in user!.uid. If user is null, this error occurs. From your screenshot, it seems you're not using any null check operators on nullable variables. So, the problem might be elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably thrown when the app is in background and the widget is not mounted anymore, there is code inside `setState` that is crashing because the context is null, you can fix that using `mounted`, like this:

```dart
FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges().listen((User? user) {
  if (mounted) {
    if (user != null) {
      setState(() {
        _createdUserId = user.uid;
      });
    } else {}
  }
});
```

More info: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/mounted.html